# ID parameter in Kohana 3 routing is NULL

Tags: php, routes, kohana-3, bootstrapping

I have a rule defined in Kohana 3 routing but the ID parameter is not being passed to the method.

I have this in the bootstrap.php file:

```
Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'home',
    'action'     => 'index',
));
```

and controller

```
public function action_home($id=NULL)
{
    echo $id;
}
```

But in the following link example, the ID is usually NULL:

> http://example.com/index/123

The ID should be `123` but it isn't. I don't know why.

Answer (score 4):

Yeah the Ko3 routes are ridiculous.

Try removing that $id=null since K03 will assign the vars as parameters:

```
public function action_home()
{
    echo $this->request->param('id');
}
```

See if that helps.

Comment: Thanks, I know this method is working. But customer want that I use standart kohana routing.

Comment: this is standard kohana routing. The URI handling may be what you're thinking of. All I am saying is that you do not need to define the expected parameters in the controller's arguments. They are passed through the request object - an infinitely more scalable solution.

Answer (score 1):

They were removed from Kohana, please see: http://dev.kohanaframework.org/issues/4357

As zombor stated:

> They just don't fit into how Kohana is designed. They should not have been included in 3.0 in the first place.

Also it isn't supposed to handle all routes with the default one. You should define as many as you need.